# Calling a MSAcces database query from an aspx in C#

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, aspxgridview, ms-access-2010

Below are the two controls I am trying to use, but neither one will allow me to get the data.  Is this something I should be doing in C#?  The select command works in MSAccess, because that is where I created it. `qcustcnt` is a query.  The select I pasted in is also a query, but VS2010 doesn't seem to want me to use them, so I tried to bring it insto VS2010.

```
 <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" 
   DataFile="~/App_Data/cbf.accdb" 
   SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCTROW customer.custsales, Count(*) AS [Count Of customer],
   qcustcnt.CountOfcustsales, [count of customer]/[countofcustsales] AS salespercent
   FROM customer, qcustcnt
   GROUP BY customer.custsales, qcustcnt.CountOfcustsales;">
  </asp:AccessDataSource>
  <telerik:RadChart ID="RadChart2" runat="server" 
       DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2">
  </telerik:RadChart>
```

Comment: Is there some error message being displayed?

Comment: The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'qcustcnt'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'qcustcnt'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.

Comment: Well, does it exist and is it spelled correctly? (verify you don't have 2 access db's your working on) Also, unrelated to your question, you might want to do a join between customer and qcustcnt-- this will create in memory a data structure with n*m rows (where n=rows in 1st and m= rows in second) and then smoosh it down. An inner join would allow the engine to optimize and not do that.

Comment: Yes it's all spelled right I did a cut & paste from Access into the select screen of the AccessDataSource Control and when I try to test it I get the same error.  I don't know why it can't see it as a stored procedure or just let me drag it from the Server view the same way you can do a table.  The qcustcnt just returns to me the number of records in the table.

Comment: Did everyone give up on this one?

Comment: I have it working now.  What I ended up doing was removing all the data Access Controls.  I added one and that allowed me to use the Queries.  When I added the second one it would not.  I don't know why but it appeered to be pointing to a database that didn't exist.  I deleted that control and copied and Paisted the first control to create a second one and that allowed me to access the Queries in the database.  I still don't know whats going on, but I have moved passed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it working now.  What I ended up doing was removing all the data Access Controls.  I added one and that allowed me to use the Queries.  When I added the second one it would not.  I don't know why but it appeered to be pointing to a database that didn't exist.  I deleted that control and copied and Paisted the first control to create a second one and that allowed me to access the Queries in the database.  I still don't know whats going on, but I have moved passed the problem.